# How can I edit a shipping address at checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

Is it possible to add an edit button for the addresses in the checkout section?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hlo! there is no default option in magento to edit shipping address at checkout page, if u want to make changes in address u can add new address it works as same .
If u want to edit at  there add custom button there and a custom form to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Jaspreet!

Answer (score 0):

You actually can with this css

button.action.edit-address-link {
display: block !important;
}